# How to get the component name from the httpInterceptor error handler service in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I need to get the exact component name, function name and line number where the error has occurred in angular ts file but I cant get them from the httpInterceptor. Please kindly help me to get the above from the httpInterceptor.

console.log(this.route.routeConfig.component.name);

I have tried the above and it gives the component name of the current working component but I have to get the component name from the httpInterceptor.

````
import { Injectable, ErrorHandler, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { catchError, retry} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable ({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class errorHandler implements HttpInterceptor{
    constructor(){
    }

    intercept(request : HttpRequest<any>, handler : HttpHandler) : Observable<HttpEvent<any>>{
        return handler.handle(request)
        .pipe(
            retry(1),
            catchError((error : any) => {
                console.log('---->'+request.headers.get('content-disposition'));
                let errorMessage = '';
                if(error.error instanceof ErrorEvent)
                    errorMessage = `Error : `+error.error.message;
                else
                    errorMessage = `Error Code : `+error.status +`\nMessage : `+error.message;

                return throwError(JSON.stringify(errorMessage));
            })
        )
    }

}```
````

Comment: Is there any specific reason for handling the error in httperror, when it could be handled in the calling the component or service?

Comment: @KiraAG Best way to handle HTTP error across the application is to implement a common **HTTPErrorInterceptor** as it will intercept every call and error can be handled easily without handling it in every service.

Comment: @KiraAG , I want to handle any error globally using the HTTP INterceptor. I also need to know which component inside the app that threw the error.

Comment: @M.Sanjay you can't know which component throw that error in your interceptor. Beacuse you are doing a `XMLHttpRequest` and you have the traceability of that stack upstream

Comment: @Shifenis If there is some other way, please kindly suggest me.

Comment: @M.Sanjay I haven't any ideas to find out a solution, only you can use `console.error` in your interceptor.
 You can read the error in console but you'll know the problem just in downstream.

Comment: Did you get the url value in `intercept` method? So based on url you can figured out the component If you have used component specific REST Apis.

Comment: @hrdkisback Actually I need to get the component name programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.trace();`

The above code helps to get the complete trace of how the error occurred along with appropriate line number, function name and the component name. So, we can use console.trace() in case of debugging, which is more useful in case to get where the error occurred.

Comment: I want to check condition on component name how do to that?